# Xslt exclude few attributes, that are loaded dynamically, from input xml

Tags: java, xml, xslt

I need to write xsl to exclude few attributes from input xml.

Note:exclude attributes will be loaded dynamically by using
transformer.setParameter("attribiutes", "A,B") method in java.

My input xml:

```
<root>
 <child1 A="" B="" C="" />
</root>
```

Below is the xsl which i was using, but its not working.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:param name="atttributes" select="''" />
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains($atttributes, @*)">
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The result should be like the below xml.

```
<root>
 <child1 C="" />
</root>
```

Kindly help me out from this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Tim C pointed out in his deleted answer, you want to limit the test to attributes only, and copy all other nodes *as is*. And you want the test to check the attribute's *name*, not its *contents*. And you want to eliminate false positives  by including delimiters in the comparison.

Try it this way:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:param name="atttributes" select="'A,B'" />

<xsl:template match="node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*">
    <xsl:if test="not(contains(concat(',', $atttributes, ','), concat(',', name(), ',')))">
        <xsl:copy/>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! you saved my hours. :)